# Can I test interrater reliability between 2 groups of unequal sample size

Tags: small-sample, agreement-statistics

Two groups (expert and semi-expert) rate items in an online survey using a 4 point Likert scale. Members of each group are asked to rate (i) the importance of problems and (ii) how useful each suggested intervention is to solve each respective problem. The aim is to refine the items to include in a finalised survey (e-delphi study). I would like to explore inter-rater reliability of ratings for each item (problem areas and supports) and totals. However, recruitment has been more positive towards one group; in fact double. However total sample size is small (n=42). Can I reliably explore inter-rater reliability by adjusting somehow. If so, any help would be gratefully appreciated. Totally new to stats and SPSS! TIA

Answer (score 0):

You might look at Krippendorff’s alpha  which [can handle unequal sample size](https://www.statisticshowto.com/krippendorffs-alpha/)  and can be [implemented in SPSS](https://www.polcomm.org/wp-content/uploads/ICR01022012.pdf)

Comment: Problem with Kripp Alpha is it's not reliability, it's chance corrected agreement. (Which might be OK, but sometimes it matters).

Comment: I appreciate the comment and its detail, but it is not totally clear to me. This measure, as well as other similar ones, is commonly used and accepted as a measure the inter-raters reliability by the scientific community, so why do you not consider it as a measure of reliability? Second, you said this could be a problem but it’s not clear to me what is the problem you refer. Could you give an example of a concrete case in which this distinction matters?